# Sails.js IO.socket not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets, sails.js

I have an AngularJS application that I was trying to just get socket firing on creation / deletion of items in my DB. I switched from using the $resource to io.socket.post() using a custom controller method ('socketCreate'), however not sure why none of my socket callbacks are firing.

Sails JS console logs the new User, new user is created, and angular gets the data back from the socket and refreshes the list. This all works correctly, however the io.socket.on callback does not fire.

Am I not getting the eventIdentity correct?

Angular Controller:

```
$scope.newUser = function() {
    io.socket.post('/users/socketCreate', {name: $scope.temp_user.name}, function( data, jwres ) {
        $scope.refreshUsers();
        $scope.temp_user = {};
    });
};

if( !io.socket.newUserListen ) {
    io.socket.newUserListen = true;
    console.log( io.socket.newUserListen );

    io.socket.on( 'users', function onServerSentEvent( msg ) {
        console.log( 'users', msg );
    });

    io.socket.on( 'user', function onServerSentEvent( msg ) {
        console.log( 'user', msg );
    });
}
```

Sails Controller:

```
module.exports = {
    socketCreate: function( req, res ) {
        var newName = req.param( 'name' );
        if( newName && req.isSocket ) {
            Users.create({ name: newName }).exec(function created( err, newGuy ){
                Users.publishCreate({
                    id:newGuy.id,
                    name: newGuy.name
                });
                console.log( 'User Created...' );
                res.ok( newGuy );
            })
        } else if( req.isSocket ) {
            Users.watch( req );
        } else {
            console.log( newName, req.isSocket );
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the event callbacks aren't firing is because you need to subscribe to the room that's being generated automatically by Sails.  One way to do this is to use Sails blueprints. So if you add this to your Angular controller you should see the events fire:

```
 io.socket.get('/users', function(data) {});
```

By making this *get* socket request you are executing the blueprint: find action which automatically subscribes the socket to the room. Alternatively you could create another action that uses the `.watch()` method to do the same thing:

```
join: function(req, res) {
  Users.watch(req);

  return res.ok();
},
```

And then call it from the controller:

```
io.socket.put('/users/join', function(data) {});
```

Comment: This worked well. Instead of using my AngularJS factory I created for the users endpoint, I ended up using io.socket.get which the callback data which equaled my $scope.users. I did have to run $scope.$apply(); though to get the view to update, but now works across multiple browsers (adding & removing data)